# Bitbucked giving me 403 when pushing despite being Admin

Tags: git, bitbucket

I own a private repo on bitbucket that I haven't used in a long while.

Lately tried to push a new branch to it using     `git push --set-upstream origin hotfix-routing` and got this info prompt in the terminal:

> remote: Forbidden
>   fatal: unable to access 'https://{{login}}@bitbucket.org/{{reponame}}.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

I use bitbucket not so ofter and am not sure how to approach this issue.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same thing but the circumstances may have been a bit different.

In my case, I use separate Bitbucket accounts for work and personal projects. I was logged into Sourcetree with my work account but trying to push from the command line to a remote repo at my personal account.

To fix my problem: I opened Sourcetree and navigated to Tools --> Options --> Authentication and changed my default account to my personal account. I returned to the command line and was able to push my commit.